# bootstrap gives conflicting results when simulate is used (LMER)

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, bootstrap, simulation

I perform a parametric bootstrap in 2 ways.

first method:

fit dataset in a H1 and H0 model(H1 contains all effects and HO has a certain effect omitted).
retrieve the log likelihood ratio (call it here OBS_LLR)

From the H0 model I save the variance of the residuals and random effects with the following command:

```
H0.model <- lmer(Y$response ~  T2+ T3 +  (1 | Y$identifirs.id), data=Y, REML = TRUE)

H1.model <-  lmer(Y$response  ~  T2+ T3 + T2C+ T3C+ T2CO+ T3CO+ T2H+ T3H+ T2L+ T3L+  (1 | Y2$identifirs.id), data=Y, REML = TRUE)

re_dat = as.data.frame(VarCorr(H0.model))

#extract random effects and residual variance
rand_effects.var <- matrix(re_dat[1,'vcov'])
resid_var <-matrix(re_dat[2,'vcov'])
```

in my bootstrap I create a new response matrix based on the fixed estimates obtained from the H0.model. I add random effects and residuals from a normal distribution with mean 0 and sd equal to the square root of the variances (  rand_effects.var and resid_var, respectively).

For each iteration I run a H1 model and a H0 model and retrieve the log likelihood ratio(call it LLR_B)
However during some iterations I get a warning

> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

and perform some calculation to obtain a P-value.

2nd method:
fit dataset in a H1 and H0 model(H1 contains all effects and HO has a certain effect omitted).
retrieve the log likelihood ratio (call it here OBS_LLR)

Now, if I use simulate() and give as input the H0.model to simulate new data perform the same bootstrap schema as above the P-value obtained shows no significance and the singular warning is not shown.

This leaves me with the following questions:

1. Are the obtained variances in the first method not the correct variances that should be used?
2. How does simulate work(does it use same fixed estimates that I collect via fixeff(H0.model)? are the same variances used?
3. The ?isSingular warning does not appear in each iteration in the first method maybe 10x per 100  iterations, is this something to be worried about?

Comment: any help would be appreciated greatly, I have been looking around and found no clear answer.